# Foreach loops (with included LINQ) performance increase

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, loops

I wish to streamline the following code containing foreach loops to minimize iterations and/or increase performance because of LINQ and collections being created on each iteration:

```
foreach (Contact contact in Contacts) // phone contacts, around 500-1000
{
    IEnumerable<ContactEmailAddress> emails = contact.EmailAddresses; // each has multiple emails

    foreach (Friend parseUser in parseUsers) // could be many thousands
    {
        if (emails.Where(e => e.EmailAddress == parseUser.Email).ToList().Count > 0)
        {                        
            parseUser.AddContact(contact); // function call

            verifiedUsers.Add(parseUser); // add to my new aggregated list
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `if(emails.Any(e => e.EmailAddress == parseUser.Email))`

Comment: Start by replacing `.ToList().Count > 0` by `.Any()`

Comment: @Romoku & Ken, while that will certainly help a bit, in that it adds short circuiting, you can do *much* better by avoiding the linear search inside of a nested loop entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than doing a linear search on the `emails` collection for each item in `parseUsers` you can use a collection that can be much more efficiently searched, such as a `HashSet`:

```
foreach (Contact contact in Contacts) // phone contacts, around 500-1000
{
    HashSet<string> emails = new HashSet<string>(
        contact.EmailAddresses.Select(e => e.EmailAddress));

    foreach (Friend parseUser in parseUsers) // could be many thousands
    {
        if(emails.Contains(parseUser.Email))
        {
            parseUser.AddContact(contact); // function call

            verifiedUsers.Add(parseUser); // add to my new aggregated list
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll have to create my own HashSet using a dictionary since WP7 doesn't support HashSet unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Not improve much performance, but improve readbility:

```
foreach (Friend parseUser in parseUsers) // could be many thousands
{
    var filterContacts = Contacts.Where(contact =>
                              contact.EmailAddresses.Contains(parseUser.Email));
    if (filterContact.Any())
    {
        parseUser.AddContacts(filterContacts);
        verifiedUsers.Add(parseUser);
    }
}
```